# How can I best describe "A rule that can be applied to itself"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For instance, the statement "most arguments are simply disagreements over definition" can itself be argued based on the definition of "argument" and perhaps even "definition".

How could I describe this?

Comment: As, I believe, Bertrand Russell said, you can't have rules of philosophy that are *self-reflexive*.

Comment: I've changed the question tags since I think you're requesting words or phrases, rather than supplying a list from which to choose, which is what [tag:word-choice] is for. Feel free to modify them or change them back as appropriate. You can hover your mouse over each tag and click *info* on the pop-up to learn more about the tags.

Comment: Related: look at [autological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word) which describes words. (perhaps _autological statement or rule_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps *self-referential* would work?

> ***[Self-Referential](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self-referential)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> (especially of a literary or other creative work) making reference to itself, its author or creator, or their other work.
>   *‘self-referential elements in Donne's poems’*

Comment: Good idea.  Perhaps also: a question that itself illustrates the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

A nice concise option would be [**metarule**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20metarule&oq=define%20metarule&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0.1969j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

> a rule governing the content, form, or application of other rules.

This is not a fool-proof option, as "metarule" often refers to a rule that governs the application of *other* rules.

---

In the example you provided, you could describe the logic of the rule as **circular logic**, or [***circulus in probando***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning)